# FCM Target condition syntax

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been unable to find any official FCM documentation that explains the correct syntax for constructing the condtion string passed to FCM in order to send targeted pushes.  I am using the excellent [Firebase Admin SDK for PHP](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud-messaging.html#changing-the-message-target) with which I can target outgoing message recipients like so

```
CloudMessage::withTarget('condition',$condition)->withNotification($notif)->withData($data);
```

Typically, I can build simple conditions such as

```
"('topicFoo' in topics) && !('topicBar' in topics)";
```

which would ensure that the message goes out to all subscribers to `topicFoo` who are not also subscribers to topic `topicBar`.  I worked this out for myself by trial and error.  But suppose I want to build  more complex condition such as

```
"(('topicFoo1' in topics) || ('topicFoo2' in topics)) && !(('topicBar1 in topics) || ('topicBar2' in topics))"
```

While I could figure this out too through a spot of trial and error it would be better to have definitive Google documentation that explains what can and cannot be done.  Is there a maximum level of condition complexity that is imposed by FCM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I know of the documentation on [sending messages to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics), which contains this section on conditions:

> To send a message to a combination of topics, specify a condition, which is a boolean expression that specifies the target topics. For example, the following condition will send messages to devices that are subscribed to `TopicA` and either `TopicB` or `TopicC`:
>
> ```
> "'TopicA' in topics && ('TopicB' in topics || 'TopicC' in topics)"
> ```
>
> FCM first evaluates any conditions in parentheses, and then evaluates the expression from left to right. In the above expression, a user subscribed to any single topic does not receive the message. Likewise, a user who does not subscribe to `TopicA` does not receive the message. These combinations do receive it:
>
> - `TopicA` and `TopicB`
> - `TopicA` and `TopicC`
>
> You can include up to five topics in your conditional expression.

There's also a code snippet for sending to topics with conditions, so I recommend checking that out in the link too.

Comment: Thanks.  While helpful it is curious that documentation on this subject should be so sketchy. It does not, for instance, mention that negations, !, can be used to EXCLUDE topics though I have found that this does work.

Comment: If you have feedback on the documentation, there's a link at the bottom of the page to leave that. That ensures the right people see it.